# Google Oauth 2.0 Token Expire Time

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, token, google-oauth, google-php-sdk

To start I am using the Google OAuth 2.0 code from this site https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

I need to find out where in this oauth directory the token expires and logs you out. I am having issues with the refresh token and usually the token expires in 1 hour and throws me an error, but I cant keep waiting for 1 hour each time I make a change to see if the code works or not. I have changed some time settings in the code to like 10 or 60 seconds but they don't do anything. Please let me know which file and where I can change the time the token expires and logs out the logged in user.

Thanks,

I have added the following code because the problem is in here, something with this get function is not renewing/using the refresh token. How can I write this code better.

```php
    $service = new Google_Service_Oauth2 ($client);

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
        //For logged in user, get details from google using access token
        $user = $service->userinfo->get();
        $user_id = filter_var($user['id'],FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $user_name = filter_var($user['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $first_name = filter_var($user['given_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $last_name = filter_var($user['family_name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        $email = filter_var($user['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        // $profile_url = filter_var($user['link'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        $profile_image_url = filter_var($user['picture'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
        $gender = filter_var($user['gender'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
        // $personMarkup = "$email<div><img src='$profile_image_url?sz=50'</div>";
        $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to change Google's access token expiry time. However, the `Google_Client::isAccessTokenExpired()` method will return `true` if the token has expired or expires in 30 seconds from now. Your code should not need to deal with renewing a token only after it fails but can check if the access token is expired  *before* it is going to call any method with that particular access token.

There's still an edge case that remains: you can simulate that by manually revoking the access token (out-of-band of your app) using:

```
curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=<access_token>
```

and then run/test your code that still holds on to the now revoked access token. The error code on access is the same for revoked or expired ("invalid_token"), and the handling is the same anyhow.